# What is the best way of learning Digital Image processing?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am quite interested in image processing. What is the best way of learning image processing -- whether to begin with MATLAB or OpenCV? I am familiar with C and C++.
Any books/videos/blogs to recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with MATLAB, for a beginner, is that it is really expensive. Some universities buy it without the Image Processing Toolbox, in which case it is not so useful. Octave is well supported by the open source community, that is another alternative

"Processing" is a language that is easy to learn and powerful. You might want to take a look at it.

OpenCV is a bit hard to learn at the start, but very powerful. There are enough examples available in OpenCV documentation pages, so I recommend OPenCV over the other two.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is easier to start with but it has limited library and slower implementation.

OpenCV, being a C/C++ library, is the most popular. You can access great tutorials and references for it. It is a well documented and open-source library. Also, there are many discussion forums, Q&A web-sites, and blogs (http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/ , http://opencv-code.com/) about it.

[SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/), being a python library, is a wrapper library on OpenCV. Hard to comment on that -since I didn't use it- but it might not cover all the broad methods of OpenCV. On the other hand, it is [easier](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZSm7Q2bZoc) to play with, however not well-known.  You may not find answers to your questions on the web.

[Here](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf) is a guide-book for OpenCV.

[Here](http://csce.uark.edu/~jgauch/5013/other/books/Practical_Computer_Vision_with_SimpleCV.pdf) is a guide-book for SimpleCV.

In any case, I suggest you not to memorize or copy. Do not ask for codes, ask for ideas. Read the books and learn about the methods you are going to use -like what convolution kernel is, what the alpha channel is, etc.- Thats what improves you and makes you capable of dealing with broader range of vision problems.

Comment: So should i go with matlab or open cv?

Comment: I cannot tell one way or another. You can go on and decide for yourself now. Also, please do not ask for opinions. Stackoverflow is not a forum but a Q&A site, so opinion based answers are not appreciated in general.

Comment: you can also use OpenCV from MATLAB: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv (really any C/C++ library can be used in MATLAB, just create a wrapper using MEX-functions)